# SQS - Delivery Delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to send data to SQS using python with delivery delay. Also, the queue already has `Delivery Delay` attribute defined ex 10 minutes.

So if I mention delivery delay as 10 minutes in code also will total delivery delay be 20 minutes or only 10 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the total delay will only be 10 minutes, since if you specify the delay in the request, it will override that of the queue.

See here for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html